# How can I use some kind of IoC (?) to automatically register routes for my ASP.NET MVC controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, asp.net-mvc-routing

Currently I've found that it's most convenient to have a separate `public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` method on each of my controllers. Then in Global.asax's `RegisterRoutes`, I call all of these methods.

Of course, this is quickly getting out of hand. Every time I add a new controller, I have to go and update `RegisterRoutes` with a boilerplate `MyNewController.RegisterRoutes(routes)` call.

My first instinct is to make all of my controllers derive from some abstract `ControllerBase` which has a `RegisterRoutes` method defined, then use some kind of reflection to find all `ControllerBase`-subclasses and call their static method.

My second instinct was to realize this is probably a solved problem, especially since it sounds suspiciously like this IoC-type stuff I've started to learn about very recently. So after some Googling didn't really turn anything up (possibly due to bad keywords), I thought I'd ask StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [Mvc Turbine](http://mvcturbine.codeplex.com/) to register my routes. You could have each controller implement `IRouteRegistrator` and register the routes you need there.